# Is it possible to use sscanf in C to create the alias command in a shell?

Tags: c, shell, command, scanf, alias

I'm currently trying to create a shell in C that will mimic specific Unix commands. Right now I'm trying to use sscanf() to create the alias command, but I keep having issues trying to get it to work. Due to these issues, I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible to use this function to create the alias command.

```
char *str=malloc(5000);
/*
...
*/


 /*Function to alias commands*/
    int aliasing(char *str)
    {
            char *new_name=malloc(5000);
            char *alias_val=malloc(5000);

            sscanf(str,"alias %s=\"%s\"", new_name, alias_val);
    }
```

To avoid posting most of the main() code, I used "..." to cut it out. My understanding of sscanf() is that it takes the input from user in the shell, str (assuming they typed in alias (something)="(unix command)"), then assigns the first %s to new_name, and the second %s to alias_val. However, new_name is being assigned the entire string after alias and alias_val isn't getting anything.

This has me questioning if it is even possible to use sscanf() this way, which brings me here. Any kind of feedback or ideas to fix the issue would be much appreciated. Also, if it's not possible to use sscanf() is there an alternative method to implementing the alias command?

Comment: `sscanf`'s parser is simpleminded.  `%s` reads everything up to a space, so it'll happily gobble up that `=`.  You might try `%[^=]`.

Comment: I've tried that, for some reason it still reads through the "=" and into the quotation marks.

Comment: Try it again.  I did, and it worked for me.  (Although you're still going to have trouble with those quotation marks.)

Comment: In answer to your question, though, yes, there are other ways of parsing a string like this; `sscanf` is not the only way.  In fact, as we've just seen, `sscanf` is not even a very good solution to this problem; there are others that are much better.

Comment: In answer to the question, "what are the better ways?": (1) Move a `char *` pointer along the string, looking for `'='` and '`"`" characters.  Stash away pointers to the interesting points in the string as you find them. Either copy the strings out to separate `char []` arrays, or insert `'\0'` characters in-line to isolate them. (2) the same, but use helper functions like `strchr`, `strspn`, and `strpbrk`.  (3) Sort of the same, but use `strtok` or `strsep`, as discussed in Werner's answer. (4) Use [lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)).

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtok instead

```
char delimiter[] = " =\"";
char *ptr;
ptr = strtok(str, delimiter); 
for(i = 0; ptr != NULL; i++) 
{
    printf("token %d: found '%s'\n", i, ptr);
    if(i == 1)
        strcpy(new_name, ptr);
    if(i == 2)
        strcpy(alias_val, ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);     
}
```

then you get three tokens: alias, {new_name} and {alias_val}

Comment: Can you help me understand how getting the three tokens would help me create the alias command? I just don't see how having the three tokens could help. Would I use a type of combination of strtok and sscanf?

Comment: updated the example, strcpy can be used to take out the result tokens.